# Aerodynamic Analysis on Mathematica

Tags: graphics

Are there any mods/addons that we can use to analyse the aerodynamics of certain objects visually?

Also, is there any built-in thing on Mathematica that allows us to analyse aerodynamics?

Comment: you can check [MathSource/7785](https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/7785/) and [aerospace-engineering](https://www.wolfram.com/solutions/industry/aerospace-engineering/)